# How to discretize stored data in numpy array using Orange?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, orange

I've got a set of data stored in a "numpy" array:

```
array([['4.8', '3.0', '1.4', '0.3', 'Iris-setosa'],
['4.6', '3.2', '1.4', '0.2', 'Iris-setosa'],
['5.3', '3.7', '1.5', '0.2', 'Iris-setosa'],
['5.0', '3.3', '1.4', '0.2', 'Iris-setosa'],
['7.0', '3.2', '4.7', '1.4', 'Iris-versicolor'], dtype='<U15')
```

- its just an example I'm not only working with iris dataset.

I'm trying to use [Orange](https://docs.orange.biolab.si/3/data-mining-library/reference/preprocess.html) to discretize these continues data.

I know that I can do something like this to get the job done:

```
import Orange
iris = Orange.data.Table("iris.tab")
disc = Orange.preprocess.Discretize()
disc.method = Orange.preprocess.discretize.EqualFreq(n=3)
d_iris = disc(iris)
```

However this method only works on orange data table and not on a numpy array.

Is there anyway to use Orange for discretizing data stored in a numpy array?

Comment: Can you not just wrap your data into an Orange table?

Comment: After doing that is it possible to turn it back to a numpy array after descrization? my functions has been written to work with numpy arrays... @G. Anderson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Orange is able to convert a Panda dataframe into Orange's table, so first convert your data into a Panda dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import Orange.preprocess as OrangePre
from Orange.data.pandas_compat import table_from_frame

x = np.array([...])
df = pd.Dataframe(x)
```

Then convert it to Orange table:

```
table = table_from_frame(df)
```

Discretize it:

```
disc = OrangePre.Discretize()
disc.method = OrangePre.discretize.EqualFreq(3)
d_data = disc(table)
```

Turn the result into a Panda dataframe again:

```
final_data = pd.DataFrame(np.array(d_data))
```

It's available in form of numpy too:

```
final_data.values
```

Answer (score 1):

`d_iris.X` is already a numpy array, but you will lose target value and header. `d_iris.Y` is the target column that you can merge with the X. Keep in mind though, that you will only see assigned bin values after discretization, which might be difficult to interpret.

```
d_iris.X[:5]
array([[0., 3., 0., 0.],
    [0., 1., 0., 0.],
    [0., 2., 0., 0.],
    [0., 2., 0., 0.],
    [0., 3., 0., 0.]])
```